# how to apply different shipping method for different country in magento

Tags: magento

I want to apply FedEx shipping method for Canada only and USPS to USA only in magento. is it possible ? if yes, then please, explain in brief ?

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty simple, all the shipping methods in Magento have such fields in their configuration (`System -> Config -> Shipping Methods`):

- `Ship to Applicable Countries`. There is 2 possible values `All Allowed Countries` and `Specific Countries`, you should use second in your case.
- `Ship to Specific Countries`. Here is the list of countries that you can select for restriction of your shipping method only for few countries.
- `Show Method if Not Applicable`. This field apears after you select `Specific Countries` in first dropdown, and if you select No in this field, shipping method won't be visible if it is not allowed for some country, otherwise it will display error message, if this method is not applicable for shipping.

    -

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need different stores for those countries. It is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000052/magento-multiple-authorize-net-gateways).

Ways of detecting the country automatically are [being discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195906/country-name-based-themeing-system-on-magento/).